# UICollectionView with custom cell, fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, custom-cell

I used `UICollectionView` to display my data, and I used a `custom cell`, in `cellForItemAt` fun App crashed when I want to assign value to label.

```
let reuseIdentifier = "brandCell"

ViewDidLoad------>

self.brandCollectionView!.register(BrandCercaCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        brandCollectionView.dataSource = self
        brandCollectionView.delegate = self


 // make a cell for each cell index path
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        // get a reference to our storyboard cell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! BrandCercaCollectionViewCell
//App crashed here --->
        cell.brandNameLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        return cell
    }
```

I attached photos for storyBoard.

Thanks.[image: labelOutlet]
[image]

[image: Custom cell]

Comment: check all the IBOutlets if they're connected...

Comment: Aren't you dequeuing a cell that doesn't exists yet ? `var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! BrandCercaCollectionViewCell; if cell == nil { cell = BrandCercaCollectionViewCell(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)}` or something like

Comment: Do you setted a reusable identifier in the field of interface builder?

Comment: @GIJOW The `dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:for:)` method doesn't return an optional.

Comment: @AhmadF it just one and you can check it the first image

Comment: @MichaelDouglas yes

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the identifier of your cell *"brandCell"* in the storyboard as the identifier for the collection view cell.

[image: Collection Reusable View]

Comment: Yes, I set it correctly, I need more solution than it, thanks for your comment.